# Lineheight of \huge text too small

Tags: titles, fontsize, line-spacing

I have the following two titles in my custom title page: (originally two different languages)

```
\begin{center}
    {\Large 
        My Thesis\\
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \textbf{\huge 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur %
            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor % <- "p"
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        } \\
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \textbf{\huge 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur %
            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temdor % <- "d"
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        }
    }
\end{center}
```

The problem is that the line height changes with the containing letters. When I replace the p with a d, the last line is printed directly under the one before. Without any space.

How can I set the line height to a fixed value and why is it so?

Document header is: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use it this way:

```
\begin{center}
    \Large 
        My Thesis

        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \bfseries\huge 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur %
            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor % <- "p"
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

            \vspace*{0.5cm}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur %
            adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temdor % <- "d"
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{center}
```

The active baselineskip at the end of the paragraph is used, the reason why you should avoid all those `\\`.